# Unresolved externals by adding an assembly file in a C project

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to make my first (assembly file usage in vs)program by adding an assembly file to the visual C++ project

**My C++ Code**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
extern "C" void TestRegisters();
int main()
{
    cout << "Testing Registers" << endl;
    TestRegisters();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

**My Assembly code**

```
.data
mybyte db 0

.code
     TestRegisters proc
        mov rax,3342
        mov rbx,2213
        mov rcx,rax
        mov mybyte,rax
        ret
     TestRegisters endp

end
```

I have also done following configuration

```
1.Using solution configuration I have made my platform x64.
2.I have also made my build coustomization setting to masm.
```

I am getting two errors.

```
1.error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals 
2.error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol TestRegisters referenced in function main
```

Although there are several post already available but that did not help me unfortunately.

Comment: You need to tell the assembler to make the code public to the world, this is usually done by using an assembler directive called "PUBLIC".

Comment: Does your assembler source include the line `PUBLIC TestRegisters` ?

Comment: I have no idea how and where to set it?

Comment: @khan in the assembly code (where else?). Also, depending on the compiler, you may need to prefix your `TestRegisters` symbol with an underscore (`_`).

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant  that did not work I tried it.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but I got the same issue recently and the answer maybe useful to someone else.

There are three basic steps needed:

1. Make your ASM function public. You can do that by typing at the beginning of the file:

   **PUBLIC** TestRegisters
2. Tell the solution how to Select the project in Solution Explorer. On the menu bar, choose Project, Build Customizations. In the Visual C++ Build Customization Files dialog box, check the checkbox next to masm(.targets,.props). Choose OK to save your selection and close the dialog box. (as described here [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/masm-for-x64-ml64-exe?view=vs-2017#add-an-assembler-language-file-to-a-visual-c-project))
3. Define the Item Type of the ASM file correctly. Right-click on the **.asm file** in the Solution Explorer. Then in General->Item Type select **Microsoft Macro Assembler** as shown in the image below.
   [image: Item Type Selection]

I think the last step was missing in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the custom build settings for masm, you need to tell the linker to include the object file generated by masm when building the exe file. Usually you add the name of the object file as additional input file.

Comment: How exactly I would do that?

Comment: In Visual Studio, open project settings, select on the left side "linker / Input", and enter the path/name of the object file generated by masm into the edit Field "Additional Input files"

Comment: Still not working.If I add folder path it gives error of cannot open ...../../Debug.obj(a long path i used ..) If i give file path then it gave same previous errors like unresolved externals and main already defined in Test.obj.

Comment: Did you added the PUBLIC keyword as suggested by others? You need it too.

Comment: At what places to put that public keyword? Another point is that there is not Additional Input files rather Additional Dependencies path.

Comment: Try to place "PUBLIC TestRegisters" right after ".code".

Comment: I am afraid that I cannot help anymore since I donot have masm to test. You need to find out 1. if the function TestRegister is exported in the object file generated, and 2. the linker uses the object file when trying to reference the function. Good luck!

Comment: I suggest you look for a worked example. But when you have the code working, you will need to allocate a 64 bit storage buffer. You have only allocated an 8 bit space with `mybyte db 0`. And if you want to use `mybyte` from your C program, that will need to be PUBLIC too.